# QtCreator autocomplete on space

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have recently started doing some Qt development. I am coming from the .NET world and Visual Studio. I am getting used to most of the differences in the IDE, but there is one thing that is driving me crazy. In Visual Studio if you start typing something it will give you the autocomplete suggestion. If you are in the middle of typing something and hit . it will finish it with what it is autocompleted on. Also if you hit space it will use the suggestion as well. In QtCreator you have to hit tab to use the suggestion. Is there any way to change this behavior to work like Visual Studio?

Comment: I think the only options are those listed at Text Editor -> Behavior -> Typing and Text Editor -> Completion.

Comment: You can try to work with Visual Studio Add-in for Qt, available under this link: 
Qt4: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe
Qt5: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.4-opensource.exe

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It requires changes to Qt Creator source code.

The relevant code is in `src\plugins\texteditor\codeassist\genericproposalwidget.cpp`, in the implementation of `GenericProposalWidget::eventFilter`. The tab, enter and return all activate the current proposal item:

```
case Qt::Key_Tab:
case Qt::Key_Return:
case Qt::Key_Enter:
    abort();
    activateCurrentProposalItem();
    return true;
```

At a minimum, you could add `case Qt::Key_Space:` there. This will prevent autocompletion from working with suggestions that contain spaces, where you want to elaborate over a space. Preferably, you'd want the space to act Visual-Studio-like only within the cpp editor, and even then to add a fallback - say Alt-Space should act as if a space character was to be passed to the completion list view in the block that begins with `if (ke->text().length() == 1`

You can then recompile Qt Creator; it's a simple matter once you have Qt installed.